# What to stage after a pre-commit hook was run?

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit

For a pre-commit hook that modifies the staged files, I need to figure out what has to be staged after the hook was run.

The pre-commit hook applies some pretty-printing on the files that should be committed. The hook does the following tasks:

- replace tabs by spaces
- remove trailing whitespace at the end of lines
- remove double empty lines <sup>*)</sup>
- if missing, add an empty line at the end of the file <sup>*)</sup>

Actions marked with **<sup>*)</sup>** are those that are causing the problem described below.

After these have been done, the hook adds the modified file(s) to the index using `git add $filename`. That way, the whole file gets staged and I'm no longer able to commit only small portions (i.e. hunks) of the modified file.

Of course, I could `git add --no-verify` and bypass the hook, but that option isn't available when using the `git gui`. Also, I **want** the took to apply pretty-printing on the staged lines of the file, so bypassing the hook is not my aim.

Is there a way to find out what has to be added to the index after the pretty-printing was applied, so that I could stage the *right* content after the hook was run instead of staging the whole file?

---

**Edit 1:**
While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514158/520162) provided by [David Brigada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042306/david-brigada) looks promising, it doesn't work: `git stash --keep-index` leaves the staged changes intact (that's the good part), but (at least on msysgit) it puts **all** changes into the stash (not only the unstaged ones). This results in merge conflicts when popping the stash back into WC because the staged lines might get modified.

---

**Edit 2:**
Also the updated answer of [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042306/david-brigada) leads to no success since git refuses to merge the stash into a dirty WC.

---

**Edit 3:**
The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514370/520162) from [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) points me to the usage of `.gitattributes`. On the first glimpse, this seems right but I find it quite confusing that the checked in version was run through a filter and the WC is different from the checked in version. At least, that was my experience and is backed up by the following remark in the [Git Book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html):

> If you commit those changes and check out the file again, you see the keyword properly substituted

I have to **remove** the file and then **check it out again** to see the changes that were applied by the filter? No way! Any more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that a pre-commit hook is the right place to perform this sort of work.  Git has a filtering mechanism that allows you to apply commit/checkout filters to documents via `.gitattributes`; the [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) includes examples that use this filtering mechanism to apply the `indent` program to C source files automatically.

Comment: this seems to be another way to achieve what I want but I have some concerns about the usability. See updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll award the bounty to you although the answer didn't really help me out of my problem. I think, there's no way to do what I want but your answer points me to `.gitattributres` which I didn't know before your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot accept the answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can put the changes that you have not staged for commit in a stash in your pre-commit script, and then pop them off when you are done.  The `--keep-index` option only stashes changes that you haven't added to the index (haven't run git add on), and the `--quiet` options suppress the notices that you're creating and destroying the stash.

The way you described isn't quite the canonical "git way to do it," most pre-commit scripts that I've seen only check for incorrect style and then error out of the commit if they find anything.  That way you don't have your pre-commit script inadvertently rewrite some file that was supposed to have tabs in it for some reason (e.g. testing data)---you could simply rerun the commit with --no-verify once you were confident that the errors were supposed to be there.

I have a simple pre-commit script here.  It pretty much just runs git's basic test of diff-index --check, but it uses the git stash to only work on the changes that it should.

```
#!/bin/sh
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

git stash save --keep-index --quiet
git diff-index --check --cached $against --
RETVAL=$?
git stash pop --quiet
exit $RETVAL
```

#### Update:

You will get merge conflicts if you try to use this strategy with a script that modifies the contents you want to commit.  We should take the stash pop out of the pre-commit script, and perform an explicit merge in the post-commit script.

```
#!/bin/sh

git stash save --keep-index --quiet
# Add your script to prettify the code here ...
git add .
```

Now the post-commit script looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

git merge stash@{0} -s recursive -Xtheirs
git stash drop --quiet stash@{0}
```

The `recursive` merge with the `theirs` parameter should keep the changes the script made when possible.

Comment: While this answer looked promising, it doesn't work. `stash --keep-index` leaves the staged changes intact, but (at least on msysgit) it puts **all** changes into the stash (not only the unstaged ones). This results in merge conflicts when popping the stash back into WC because the staged lines might get modified...

Comment: @eckes: I changed the stash pop to an explicit merge attempting to keep the changes the script made.  See if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looks even more promising but does also not help: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 path/to/foo.h
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the goal, but perhaps you could try the following approach. Have your hook generate a patch instead of writing the changes to disk. (You could do this, e.g., in Python using the `difflib` module, or write a temp file and shell out to `diff`.) Then use `git apply` (with `--cached` and other flags as appropriate) to apply your patch to the index as well as to the working tree (either manually or automatically by the hook).

Answer (score 0):

Since my goal does not seem to be achievable, I helped me with another solution:

I only stage parts of files when I'm in the `git gui`. Luckily, the `git gui` lets you add custom commands to the `Tools` menu. I set up a script called `hooks.sh` that receives one parameter, either `enable` or `disable`. This script is added to the `Tools` menu, once with `enable`, once with `disable` as parameter.

That way, I could comfortable disable the hook when staging just a part of the file, then commit and then enable the hook again.

There you go:

```
#!/bin/sh

################################################################################
# hooks.sh                                                                     #
# enable or disable git hooks.                                                 #
################################################################################

THEHOOK=pre-commit                  # which hook to work with
ENABLEDFILE=./.git/hooks/$THEHOOK   # original name of the file
DISABLEDFILE=$ENABLEDFILE.disabled  # disabled name of the file
OLDFILE=''                          # for mv command: old name
NEWFILE=''                          # for mv command: new name

# parse parameters
case $1 in
  disable)
    OLDFILE=$ENABLEDFILE
    NEWFILE=$DISABLEDFILE
    ;;
  enable)
    OLDFILE=$DISABLEDFILE
    NEWFILE=$ENABLEDFILE
    ;;
  *)
    echo -e "operation:\n    $0 enable  to enable the hook\n    $0 disable to disable the hook"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

if [ -e $OLDFILE ]
then
  mv $OLDFILE $NEWFILE
else
  echo "nothing to do"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have a pre-commit hook that does your described actions but then *also* a commit-msg hook.

This is how I would solve the problem:

1. Add the following pre-commit hook:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACM |
           xargs -r0 YOUR_SMUDGE_SCRIPT
   git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACM |
           xargs -r0 git add -u -v --
   ```
2. Add the following commit-msg hook:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   awk '!/^[[:space:]]*(#|$)/{exit f++}END{exit !f}' "$1" && exit
   # NOTREACHED unless commit was aborted
   git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACM |
           xargs -r0 YOUR_CLEAN_SCRIPT
   git diff --cached --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACM |
           xargs -r0 git add -u -v --
   ```

Taking care to replace YOUR_CLEAN_SCRIPT and YOUR_SMUDGE_SCRIPT with the command-name you want to run that will do the actual clean/smudge routines. The smudge routine should expand keywords (occurring pre-commit) and the clean routine should undo the changes (occurring when a commit gets aborted). These scripts will be passed the files that need to be modified (previously staged for a different edit).